# Using Hazelcast IMDG as JPA second level cache in Wildfly (15)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly, hazelcast

Anybody knowing a way to use Hazelcast IMDG as JPA/Hibernate second level cache in Wildfly 15?

In my setup, Wildlfy is always using builtin Infinispan as soon as I activate 2nd level caching in my persistence.xml using

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
```

It seems that property *hibernate.cache.region.factory_class* isn't evaluated at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with

```
<property name="wildfly.jpa.regionfactory" value="false" />
```

it is possible to deactivate Wildfly's default behaviour of direct coupling to Infinispan. This makes it possible to use another 2nd level caching backend. (E.g. Hazelcast)

Thanks to Martin in [JBoss Developer Forum](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/279911)